Adopt target format into the existing table in the slide
the following code missing to spread data into proportionate rows and columns from the source into the target.
eg if trying to paste 2col & 2row data of source table into target table.. it pastes the entire first row of source into the first column of target and entire second row of source into the second column and so on.
It should paste with the correct distribution and enclose the sample image for the error reference.
Sub PasteDataWithTargetFormat()
    ' This macro pastes data into consecutive cells of an existing table
    ' and adopts the target format of the table.
    
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptShape As Shape
    Dim pptTable As Table
    Dim dataToPaste As String
    Dim dataArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim cellIndex As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer, startCol As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Integer, colCount As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim currentRow As Integer, currentCol As Integer
    
    ' Get the active slide
    Set pptSlide = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    
    ' Loop through all shapes in the slide
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
        ' Check if the shape is a table
        If pptShape.HasTable Then
            Set pptTable = pptShape.Table
            rowCount = pptTable.Rows.Count
            colCount = pptTable.Columns.Count
            
            ' Get the selected cell's row and column
            found = False
            For i = 1 To rowCount
                For j = 1 To colCount
                    If pptTable.Cell(i, j).Selected Then
                        startRow = i
                        startCol = j
                        found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                If found Then Exit For
            Next i
            
            ' If a cell is selected
            If found Then
                ' Get data from clipboard
                dataToPaste = GetClipboardText()
                
                ' Split the data by line breaks to get multiple lines
                dataArray = Split(dataToPaste, vbCrLf)
                
                ' Initialize the cellIndex
                cellIndex = 0
                
                ' Initialize currentRow and currentCol to start from the selected cell
                currentRow = startRow
                currentCol = startCol
                
                ' Paste data into consecutive cells
                Do While cellIndex <= UBound(dataArray)
                    If currentRow <= rowCount And currentCol <= colCount Then
                        With pptTable.Cell(currentRow, currentCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                            .Text = dataArray(cellIndex)
                            ' Apply formatting from target cell
                            .Font.Name = pptTable.Cell(startRow, startCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name
                            .Font.Size = pptTable.Cell(startRow, startCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size
                            .Font.Bold = pptTable.Cell(startRow, startCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold
                            .Font.Italic = pptTable.Cell(startRow, startCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic
                            .Font.Underline = pptTable.Cell(startRow, startCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Underline
                            .Font.Color = pptTable.Cell(startRow, startCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color
                        End With
                        cellIndex = cellIndex + 1
                        ' Move to the next cell
                        currentCol = currentCol + 1
                        If currentCol > colCount Then
                            currentCol = 1
                            currentRow = currentRow + 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            Else
                MsgBox "Please select a cell in the table where you want to start pasting the data.", vbExclamation
            End If
        End If
    Next pptShape
End Sub

Function GetClipboardText() As String
    ' This function retrieves text from the clipboard
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    GetClipboardText = DataObj.GetText
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    GetClipboardText = ""
    MsgBox "Clipboard is empty or does not contain text.", vbExclamation
End Function



actually the ppt macro to pastes data into consecutive cells of an existing table and adopts the target format of the table where in the cursor placed cell in the target table

I believe the dataArray getting split only by rows not columns. so how to split that clipboard dataArray into row and column data? pls help
